# Cycle Through Worksheet and Delete Sheets that Contain Specific Text

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to figure out a resolution, but basically I have a macro that combines multiple workbooks including some worksheets I don't particularly need but others on my team may.

Basically I am trying to make a second portion/sub of the Macro that would delete all sheets in the workbook that do not contain the word "Master" since all the sheets I need include that.

The sheets that I need in particular do not follow a set guideline so they may be called "Sheet Master" or "MASTER 01.01.2019", etc.

Below is what I have at the moment:

```
Sub Sheet_Delete()

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = n To 1 Step -1
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not InStr(1, Sheets(i).Name, "MASTER") Then Sheets(i).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .AlertBeforeOverwriting = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I suggest two things 1. Get rid of `On Error Resume Next`, so you can see if you are running into any errors.  2.  Instead of using`InStr`, I would use `Like` to search the names of the worksheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will delete sheets that do not have the name "MASTER" in them.  The `Option Compare Text` will remove the case sensitivity check.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub Sheet_Delete()

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = n To 1 Step -1
    If Not Worksheets(i).Name Like "*MASTER*" Then
        Worksheets(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .AlertBeforeOverwriting = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it worked.  Please accept the answer so that if others are running into the same situation it will show up in their search.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the code name rather than the tab name and loop the worksheets collection instead of using the Index. In the Properties Pane if you name your master something like myMaster you won't run the chance that the worksheet name gets changed to no longer have MASTER in it, you run your code and then your master gets deleted accidentally.

```
Dim currWS As Worksheet
   For Each currWS in ThisWorkbook.WOrksheets
      If currWS.CodeName <>"myMaster" Then
         currWS.Delete
      End If
Next
```

Comment: From my understanding the OP is adding multiple worksheets from multiple workbooks into one workbook then wants to delete the sheets that do not have a name like "MASTER" in it, so with my understanding of your answer the OP would need to go in and re-name the code name of all sheets that have a variation of the word "MASTER" in it.  I maybe misunderstaning though.

Comment: @ZackE - ah yes missed that in my first reading. OTOH, if the books being imported are in any way originally controlled by the OP I would definitely work with the code name as it appears others that work with the workbooks do rename the tabs. Suppose that one of those changes is from "somethingMaster" to someMSTR to shorten the tab name then looking for "Master" is going to delete that sheet.

Comment: I totally agree with using code names for the sheet reference, which could be built into the code as well.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Unfortunately the original books aren't controlled by me, but luckily all the sheets I do need from these files do contain the word "Master" in the sheet name (like "Master Record, or "11.22.2019 Master Sheet" - they just happen to have like 4 or 5 other sheets that people add (pivots, graphs, etc) that are good for those workbooks but not what my particular team would utilize.